# How to trace laravel db connections instances for any query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

How to trace for Mysql db connection(mysql connections) in Laravel ?

Let me explain it more, I have a db, and I want to know currently how many connections are open to that mysql Db (through mysql prompt ? or any way on ubuntu ), as my laravel application is  utilizing that mysql db instance.

And for a particular query how can I know, which connection instance(hoping some type of resource object) is being used.

If there any way please let me know ?

Comment: might be helpful: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-show-mysql-open-database-connections-on-linux-unix/

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thank you for providing links